# Best Practice for handling cascading dropdowns other postback scenarios in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have seen a few examples of handling cascading dropdowns in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery and Ajax. Of course, this requires javascript to be enabled. Assuming javascript is disabled what would be a best practice for handling cascading dropdowns.

Here is a real-world scenario of a asp.net web form I develop for a inventory app for th company I work. On the web page I have cascading dropdowns. For this example, say a dropdown of Car Makes and a Car Model which depends on the selected Car Make. Also, on this form I have a user control which implements a search feature so the user can enter the city and or state, select search, and select the customer from a gridview, which triggers an event to store the Customer ID in a field for the current order on the web page. I'm not using javascript on this page. The dropdown triggers a postback and reloads the dropdown values in the 2nd dropwdown. The search user control causes postbacks when the user clicks the Find button and when the user chooses the customer from the gridview.

How would this be handled in MVC? Would the postbacks in my example equate to actions in MVC? Would there be an action for the changing of Car Make? An action for the search? An action for the selection from the gridview?

Comment: You seem to be saying that you managed to achieve cascading drop downs with ASP.NET Forms with Javascript disabled.  How is that possible?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Unless he included a 'populate' button, it's not.

Comment: He probably just has a continue/next button and the other dropdown is hidden until after the postback.

Comment: You can have a populate button like Richard said.  I'm not only referring to cascading dropdowns.  That's just one example.  I also have a user control that is used as a search feature in one case to find an address for an order.  I'm wondering if there are examples of best practices in asp.net mvc to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's an significant amount of data, you should consider using <optgroup> tags to show your grouping. It's also a nicer thing to do from an accessibility point of view.

Though it's worth noting that optgroups only work for one level of a hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I am with a scenario where I have three dropdowns and value of each is dependent on the value of previous one.

> I know whenever the form gets posted
>   it goes to a particular ActionName and
>   by default it will be the same as the
>   aspx page name, so if it is
>   Index.aspx, when posted it call the
>   method Index() sitting in its
>   controller.

The above behaviour was causing a bit problem so

```
From:<%=Html.DropDownList("From", (SelectList)ViewData["From"], new { onchange = "this.form.action='Index'; this.form.submit();" })%>
To :<%=Html.DropDownList("To", (SelectList)ViewData["To"], new { onchange = "this.form.action='GetTo'; this.form.submit();" })%>
```

I changed the action name to 'GetTo' first and then posting the data, so it will go to GetTo method of the controller rather than Index().

Over here I am using javascript to change the action name and then submitting the form.

Hope this might help.